# How to map a URL to an attachment

Tags: 7, files, uri, path-aliases

I'd like to have a simple and clean URL for a PDF file, such as

```
http://www.examples/file1
```

that maps to an attachment in a Drupal node, rather than using something like

```
http://www.examples/sites/default/files/files/file1.pdf
```

I've tried using URL Aliases, but Drupal complains and won't let me create the alias.  I can obviously do this with Apache redirects (with mod_rewrite) or (gasp!) with a meta tag refresh, but both seem inferior to being able to manage it from within Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/file_aliases) module for this.

Comment: Thanks!  This is good to know, but both that module and its dependency are in beta.  Have you used this in production successfully, and extensively?

Comment: Not extensively but used it a few weeks ago in a newsletter to have some nicer URLs (and it worked!)

Comment: No longer supported